# KafkaStreams handling late events when using windowing

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

**Question:**
If an event arrives after the window has closed, then, how do we re-direct it to another topic for handling the correction ?

**Context:**

- We use tumbling windows
- We use events source creation time(event-time) for defining windows

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no API to do that. Late events are dropped and you cannot get a hand on them easily.

What you could do is, to have an upstream operator (like a `transform()`) before the window, the compares the record timestamp to the current "stream time" (you would need to track "stream time" manually within the operator) -- this should help you to detect if the downstream window will drop the record as late and react to it accordingly (for example using a `branch()` after `transform()` and before `groupByKey().windonwedBy()`.

Comment: Is there any feature request for adding a late event handler API ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But I guess it would make sense to add.